# How to select elements from a list of list such that it is distinct on the basis of position '0' and sorted on the basis of element at position '1'?

Tags: python, list

How to select elements from a list of list such that it is distinct on the basis of position '0' and sorted on the basis of element at position '1'?

My list looks like:
[['difficult', 1.0, 'difficult', 1], ['new update', 0.95765316, 'new', 1], ['not easy to use', 0.9401928, 'make', 1], ['server connection', 0.9276604, 'device', 1], ['hate', 0.911795, 'remember', 1], ['good looking', 0.9098221, 'old', 1], ['not easy to use', 0.90919787, 'forget', 1], ['not useful', 0.90617406, 'different', 1], ['server connection', 0.88630825, 'access', 1], ['good looking', 0.8700615, 'almost', 1], ['not user friendly', 0.86913043, 'slack account', 1], ['difficult', 0.8670747, 'impossible', 1], ['new update', 0.86446935, 'channel', 1], ['file share', 0.8606522, 'account', 1], ['notification', 0.85776645, 'password', 1], ['user experience', 0.8487474, 'user', 1], ['tedious', 0.8434791, 'inconvenient', 1], ['slow server', 0.842572, 'slack channel', 1], ['upgrade', 0.839996, 'laptop', 1], ['file share', 0.8381065, 'link', 1], ['good looking', 0.8201821, 'outside', 1], ['automate', 0.7614835, 'navigate', 1], ['not useful', 0.71724087, 'slack', 1], ['functionality', 0.6392711, 'credential', 1]]

Comment: Use a minimal example.  Format it so it's readable.  Show us some code so we can help debug it.

Comment: If there are two elements with the same key in position 0, which one you want to keep as unique?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sort:

```
sorted(l, key=lambda e: e[1])
```

Not clear how to address your "distinct" requirement as you need to tell us which element to keep when there are duplicates on the key.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this function to do solve the proble. It works for my usecase. However, there can be better options.
Please suggest if any.
"a" is a list here.

```
def top_three_topic(a):
    c=[]
    for i in a:
        a.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
        #c.append((a)[-3:])
    a=a[::-1]

    count=0
    c.append(a[0])
    for i in range(len(a)):
        flag=0
        for j in range(len(c)):
            if (a[i][0] == c[j][0]):
                flag=1
                continue
        if(flag==0):       
            c.append(a[i])
            count+=1

        if count==2:
            break
    return c
```